# Transitionstyle of UIViewController presented modally

Tags: iphone

I am using the below statement to define the transitionstyle

```
_viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

in the below code but the above statement is not flipping horizontally while presenting it modally

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIModalTransitionStyle *modalTransitionStyle;
@synthesize modalTransitionStyle; 


self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];

[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

_viewController = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];

UIBarButtonItem * button = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:    UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView:)] autorelease];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];

UIBarButtonItem * button = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:    UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView:)] autorelease];

[_viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:button animated:YES];

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];

_viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:_viewController animated:YES];
```

Anyone knows that why it is so. When everthing is coded programmtically.

Thanks for help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong way to approach the problem. I suggest you to review your code in order to improve readability and maintainability.

Supposing that you've a viewcontroller with a target action associated with a button, something like this:

```
...
[aButton addTarget:self 
            action:@selector(dismissView:) 
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
```

You can write a selector method, in order to display your new viewcontroller as follow:

```
- (void)dismissView:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    secondVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; 
    [self presentModalViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
    [secondVC release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of confusing naming going on here.

AFAICT, _viewController is the root view controller of your navigationController.  But you reference self.viewController... is this the same view controller?  If so, why are you not consistently using accessor methods?  If not, it's not clear to me that you setting the modal transition style on the correct view controller ([self viewController] vs. _viewController).

(Btw, *please* work on formatting your code so that it displays in a more reasonable way when you paste it in.)

Comment: i fixed that .Thanks for pointing it out. But still it is not working.

Comment: OK, then please post updated code reflecting the change, along with any @synthesize lines... at a glance it looks like things are reasonable, so we need more context around what you are doing.